# Knockout JS "value" binding not working in Edge

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js

I have a small form with same data listed in multiple text areas and a new text area field at the end with "value" binding when pressing the save button it works in chrome but has issues only in EDGE

```
 <textarea class="input"
                                  maxlength="200"
                                  placeholder="Enter your text here..." 
                                  data-bind="disable: !$data.Editable(), value: $data.BodyText, 
                                  >
 </textarea>
```

what am I missing here

Comment: perhaps replace the comma after $data.BodyText with a double quote?

Comment: And please, you have enough streetcreds to know you should provide a small code snippet / fiddle that demonstrates the non-working-code, at the very least add a js-viewmodel..

Answer (score 0):

For `input` (text) and `textarea` elements, you should use the `textInput` binding since it provides instant updates on user input.

Comment: incorrect, value is usable, it just updates onblur. this depends completely on the way the developer wants to represent the data to the user